Error when downloading Python PyQt5-tools: can´t find wrapt module
I´m trying do download Python packages to be installed on another computer with no Internet access.
I could successfully download PyQt5 package, but I´m encountering an error when downloading PyQt5-tools.
H:\>pip download pyqt5 -d "C:\\Users\***\\Desktop\\offline_packs"
Collecting pyqt5
Using cached PyQt5-5.15.10-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip\<13,\>=12.13 (from pyqt5)
Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.13.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (524 bytes)
Collecting PyQt5-Qt5\>=5.15.2 (from pyqt5)
Using cached PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl.metadata (552 bytes)
Using cached PyQt5-5.15.10-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl (6.8 MB)
Using cached PyQt5_Qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (50.1 MB)
Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.13.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (77 kB)
Saved c:\\users\***\\desktop\\offline_packs\\pyqt5-5.15.10-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl
Saved c:\\users\***\\desktop\\offline_packs\\pyqt5_qt5-5.15.2-py3-none-win_amd64.whl
Saved c:\\users\***\\desktop\\offline_packs\\pyqt5_sip-12.13.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl
Successfully downloaded pyqt5 PyQt5-Qt5 PyQt5-sip

so far so good. I downloaded pyqt5 and could install it on the offline machine
H:\>pip download pyqt5-tools -d "C:\\Users\*\*\*\\Desktop\\offline_packs"
Collecting pyqt5-tools
Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.9.3.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting click (from pyqt5-tools)
Using cached click-8.1.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.9 (from pyqt5-tools)
Using cached PyQt5-5.15.9-cp37-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pyqt5-tools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
Collecting pyqt5-tools
Using cached pyqt5_tools-5.15.4.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.3 kB)
Collecting pyqt5==5.15.4 (from pyqt5-tools)
Using cached PyQt5-5.15.4.tar.gz (3.3 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[27 lines of output\]
pyproject.toml: line 7: using '\[tool.sip.metadata\]' to specify the project metadata is deprecated and will be removed in SIP v7.0.0, use '\[project\]' instead
pip_system_certs: ERROR: could not register module: No module named 'wrapt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip_vendor\\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 353, in \<module\>
main()
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip_vendor\\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 335, in main
json_out\['return_val'\] = hook(**hook_input\['kwargs'\])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pip_vendor\\pyproject_hooks_in_process_in_process.py", line 152, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-97ch848z\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\sipbuild\\api.py", line 46, in build_wheel
project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('wheel',
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-97ch848z\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\sipbuild\\abstract_project.py", line 92, in bootstrap
project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-97ch848z\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\sipbuild\\project.py", line 587, in setup
self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-download-5ulipd1p\\pyqt5_0e4bcde731af4d0a8f5d58657b365429\\project.py", line 63, in apply_user_defaults
super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-97ch848z\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyqtbuild\\project.py", line 51, in apply_user_defaults
super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
File "C:\\Users\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-97ch848z\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\sipbuild\\project.py", line 237, in apply_user_defaults
self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
File "C:\\Users\*\*\*\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-97ch848z\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\pyqtbuild\\builder.py", line 50, in apply_user_defaults
raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─\> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Apparently the error occuring during metadata preparations is pip_system_certs: ERROR: could not register module: No module named 'wrapt'. Though, I can find wrapt correctly installed:
H:\>pip list
Package          Version

-----------------------

pip              24.0
pip-system-certs 4.0
PyQt5            5.15.10
PyQt5-Qt5        5.15.2
PyQt5-sip        12.13.0
wrapt            1.16.0

Has anybody an idea of what could be the issue?
Thank you all.
Y.
Trying to install wrapt results in
H:\>pip install wrapt
Requirement already satisfied: wrapt in c:\users\yscuratti\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (1.16.0)

I also made sure to have the updated version of wrapt
H:\> pip install wrapt --upgrade --ignore-installed --user
Collecting wrapt
  Using cached wrapt-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.8 kB)
Using cached wrapt-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (37 kB)
Installing collected packages: wrapt
Successfully installed wrapt-1.16.0

